# Is there a point to wrapping a stored procedure in a transaction if no try/catch or exception logic to rollback is used?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, transactions

I have noticed my company has a lot of stored procedure scripts that look similar to this:

```
alter procedure MyProcedure
    @ItemID int
as
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- Do some stuff, maybe only 1 insert/update statement, maybe many
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The point is, there are no try/catch blocks, and no 'if' statements that do a rollback. Rollback is **never used** anywhere in the code.

So what is the point of the transaction, then? Are there other benefits to wrapping inside a transaction that I don't know about? I always thought the reason was to use rollback if something goes wrong.

Could there be logic outside the scope of this procedure that gives meaning to this?

Given my limited knowledge, not only does it seem pointless but it seems dangerous because if something goes wrong, the commit would never get executed (correct?), and then you have an open transaction and table is locked indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the update fails part way through it will rollback (well more specifically fail to commit, but it amounts to a rollback) when the session closes. It's discussed in detail [here](http://www.firstsql.com/tutor5.htm), but the relevant part is:

> Transactions ... Has no persistent effect whatever on the database, through:
>   the action of the ROLLBACK Statement,
>   abnormal termination of the client requesting the transaction, or
>   abnormal termination of the transaction by the DBMS. This may be an action by the system (deadlock resolution) or by an administrative agent, or it may be an abnormal termination of the DBMS itself. In the latter case, the DBMS must roll back any active transactions during recovery.

Basically they have set it up so the procedure never partially executes. With that said, that may not always be the ideal way to do due to performance and locking concerns, but without more specifics I really couldn't say.